# Creating a new column with value of another column, conditioned on multiple other columns shared across indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I working with a data set in pandas of about 118k observations of games played, and there should be two entries for each observation. When I come across entry A for the first time, I need to find the other observation based on three values in the current observation, and create a new column with the value of a different column. Sorry if this doesn't render correctly on all devices...I'm not sure how to format a pandas table on SO, but my data sort of looks like this:

```
   date | user_a_id | user_b_id | a_points | b_points | b_wins | a_result
0  12.1     20834     65168         65165      10568      5         W
1  12.1     20834     84163         65165      88452     21         W
2  12.2     20834     61806         65165      25998     19         L
3  12.1     84163     20834         88452      65165     33         L
4  12.3     96844     10196         22609      167005    52         W
```

There's a bunch of extra data for each player included, but the value we need to create a new column is in `b_wins`. Each row is the story of a single game, but with `a_result` being the game's result for User A. `b_wins` is a useful piece of data that tells us how much experience a player has going into the match, which I believe will have high predictive value, so dropping it would be ill advised.

In this example case, rows 1 and 3 tell the story of the same game. I need the value of `df.iloc[3].at['b_wins']` to go to a new column called `a_wins` at `df.iloc[1]`, and vice versa. The resultant two indicies would look like this:

```
   date | user_a_id | user_b_id | a_points | b_points | b_wins | a_result | a_wins
1  12.1     20834     84163         65165      88452     21         W         33
3  12.1     84163     20834         88452      65165     33         L         21
```

Some caveats about the data:

- Not every game has a pair. This data was scraped from a website and is quite messy. It's possible that there's only one observation and that's ok.
- There's no game ID, so I can only match the dates and the switched user ID numbers.
- There are plenty of rematches. So while I can match the switched ID numbers, I haven't been able to filter them by date as well
- Most of my work so far has taken place in a Colab Notebook. I've starting using the python shell for the first time and no dice.

What I've tried:

`df['a_wins'] = df['user_a_id'].apply(lambda x: df.loc[df["user_b_id"] == x, "b_wins"].values)`

The appears to work sporadically. I don't get every value, and it doesn't get rematches. To try and filter by date I then tried:

```
for i in df['date']:
  grouped = df.groupby['date'].get_group(i)
  df['a_wins'] = grouped['user_a_id'].apply(lambda x: grouped.loc[grouped["user_b_id"] == x, "b_wins"].values)
```

Also only works sporadically. Both take forever! :)

Answer (score 1):

Creating missing columns:

```
# initialise a_wins, b_result
df['a_wins'] = None
df['b_result'] = df['a_result'].replace({'W':'L','L':'W'})
```

Idea is to swap content such that the smaller `id` is always `a`:

```
# which values to swap
df['swap'] = df['user_a_id'] > df['user_b_id']
```

Create list with respective column names

```
# works for the data you posted, might want to adjust.
a_list = sorted([a for a in df.columns if 'a_' in a])
b_list = sorted([b for b in df.columns if 'b_' in b])
```

swap `a` / `b` content wherever switching condition is met:

```
for a, b in zip(a_list, b_list):
    df.loc[df['swap'], a], df.loc[df['swap'], b] = df[df['swap']][b], df[df['swap']][a]
```

output:

```
date    user_a_id   user_b_id   a_points    b_points    b_wins  a_result    swap    a_wins  b_result
0   12.1    20834   65168   65165   10568   5   W   False   None    L
1   12.1    20834   84163   65165   88452   21  W   False   None    L
2   12.2    20834   61806   65165   25998   19  L   False   None    W
3   12.1    20834   84163   65165   88452   None    W   True    33  L
4   12.3    10196   96844   167005  22609   None    L   True    52  W
```

### edit:

Duplicating the entries can now be done by grouping by `date, user_a_id, user_b_id` and filling the `None` values:

```
df = df.groupby(['date','user_b_id', 'user_a_id'])[df.columns].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
```

And now, you can use the swap column to restore the original format:

```
for a, b in zip(a_list, b_list):
    df.loc[df['swap'], a], df.loc[df['swap'], b] = df[df['swap']][b], df[df['swap']][a]
```

output:

```
date    user_a_id   user_b_id   a_points    b_points    b_wins  a_result    a_wins  b_result    swap
0   12.1    20834   65168   65165   10568   5.0 W   33.0    L   False
1   12.1    20834   84163   65165   88452   21.0    W   33.0    L   False
2   12.2    20834   61806   65165   25998   19.0    L   33.0    W   False
3   12.1    84163   20834   88452   65165   33.0    L   21.0    W   True
4   12.3    96844   10196   22609   167005  52.0    W   NaN L   True
```

Comment: After a lot of exploration I've discovered that all this does is switch a => b and b =>a without creating any new data in any observation. Interesting solution, though (and super quick) so I upvoted it, but it doesn't solve my problem. `b_wins` will always have a value, even if there isn't a matching game in my dataframe.

Comment: I must have misunderstood something in your question. Thanks for the upvote, though. I edited it such that it swaps -> fills missing values -> swaps back. This should be fast enough in a 100k row dataframe.